# Web Service Client in JBOSS 5.1 with JDK6

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jdk6

This is a continuation of the question here:
[JBoss - does app have to be compiled under same jdk as JBOSS is running under?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435286/jboss-does-app-have-to-be-compiled-under-same-jdk-as-jboss-is-running-under)

It's different enough though that it required a new question.

I am trying to use jdk6 to run JBOSS 5.1, and I downloaded the JDK6 version of JBOSS 5.1. This works fine and my EAR application deploys fine. However, when I want to run a web service client with code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("creating the web service client...");
    TestClient client = new TestClient("http://localhost:8080/tc_test_project-tc_test_project/TestBean?wsdl");
    Test service = client.getTestPort();
    System.out.println("calling service.retrieveAll() using the service client");
    List<TestEntity> list = service.retrieveAll();
    System.out.println("the number of elements in list retrieved using the client is " + list.size());
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.handleRemoteException(ClientImpl.java:396)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:302)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:170)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:150)
```

Now, **here's the really interesting part**. If I change the JDK that my the code above is running under from JDK6 to JDK5, the exception above goes away!  It's really strange.

The only way I found for the code above to run under JDK6 was to take the JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed folder and copy it to JDK6_HOME/lib.  This seems like it shouldn't be necessary, but it is.

Is there any other way to make this work other than using the workaround I just described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks roughly as if you ran into the presence of JAX-WS as an official feature of JDK 1.6. Don't copy things to 'lib', copy them to an 'endorsed' directory (one listed in java.endorsed.dirs). [This](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2007/Dec/msg00299.html) might be helpful.

If you have an up-to-date 1.6, you can get around this the same way that [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org) does. See the documentation for information on how to use CXF in a 1.6 environment.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I took the JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed folder and copied it to JDK6_HOME/lib, so I ended up with JDK6_HOME/lib/endorsed. Did you mean something else?

Comment: As far as i know JBoss does not use the JDK/lib/endorsed folder. You need to put all jars required by all webapps into the JBOSS/lib/endorsed folder.

Answer (score 2):

There are various suggestions and explanations in the respective [bug report](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBWS-1439) and elsewhere (e.g. [here](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/jboss-user/2008-June/122646.html) and [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/cxf-user@incubator.apache.org/msg03496.html)). I don't know how well they work.

Answer (score 0):

Information about this issue you can find in  JBoss official Installation And Getting Started Guide:
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html/Installation_Alternatives.html